# AutoIt ControlClick not working with hidden window

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm using ControlClick to click proceed button in browser, but when window is hidden nothing happend (with not hidden window everything works like a charm). This proceed button should call an activeX element.

```
$ie = _IECreate($Url, 0, 0)
$next = _IEGetObjById($ie, "BTNPOSTAUTH")
$iScreenX = _IEPropertyGet($next, "screenx")
$oiScreenY = _IEPropertyGet($next, "screeny")
$iBrowserX = _IEPropertyGet($next, "browserx")
$iBrowserY = _IEPropertyGet($next, "browsery")
$iWidth = _IEPropertyGet($next, "width")
$iHeight = _IEPropertyGet($next, "height")

$click = ControlClick(_IEPropertyGet($ie, "hwnd"), "", "", "left", 1, $iBrowserX+$iWidth - 10, $iBrowserY+$iHeight/2)
```

P.S. Previous controlClick for calling upload window worked fine.

Comment: What is the control id of the button you're trying to push?

Answer (score 0):

It can't work because you aren't using the ID of the control, you are performing a mouse click with the wrong function.

Use `_IEAction`

Sample :

```
$ie = _IECreate($Url, 0, 0)
$next = _IEGetObjById($ie, "BTNPOSTAUTH") ; Get Obj of element by ID
_IEAction($next , "click") ; Use "click" event on the Element "$next"
_IELoadWait($ie) ; Wait for IE until the page is load
```

**[_IEAction](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAction.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running the scripts on Windows 8, make sure to run the exe as Administrator. Right click on exe and select Run As Administrator